# Question about priority and how spells would resolve

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Fleecemane Lion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFleecemane%20Lion%5d) enters the battlefield from hand on the owners turn.

Opponent casts [Terminate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerminate%5d) on Fleecemane Lion.

Owner of Fleecemane Lion makes it monstrous.

This would make Terminate invalid correct?

Then following this, opponent casts [Chaos Warp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChaos%20Warp%5d), again targeting Fleecemane Lion.

Would chaos warp then resolve before the ability can complete and give it Hexproof?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the sequence of events.

[Fleecemane Lion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFleecemane%20Lion%5d) is on the battlefield.

Opponent casts terminate on Fleecemane Lion and passes priority.

In response, owner activates Fleecemane Lion's monstrous ability (which can be done at anytime the owner has priority) and passes priority.

At this point, the stack has on it (in top down order)

- Fleecemane Lion Monstrous
- Terminate targeting Fleecemane Lion

Now your opponent, realizing that if this stack resolves, his terminate will do nothing, casts [Chaos Warp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChaos%20Warp%5d) and passes priority.

- Chaos Warp targeting Fleecemane Lion.
- Fleecemane Lion Monstrous
- Terminate targeting Fleecemane Lion.

Two different things can happen next.  If you have enough mana, you can activate Fleeceman Lion's monstrous ability a second time.  If you do so, and this stack resolves, the Fleecemane lion will stay on the battlefield, and be monstrous.

If you don't have enough mana, and have to let the stack resolve as it is above, then the Chaos Warp will resolve before Fleecemane Lion gets it's hexproof, and it goes into the deck.

In both cases, the terminate will fizzle, as either the Fleecemane Lion will be off the battlefield, or have hexproof.

Comment: What if during the shuffling from Chaos Warp, Fleecemane Lion gets shuffled onto the top of the library?

Comment: @Acccumulation Then it counts as a different Fleecemane Lion, and none of the stuff already on the stack is targeting it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct on all accounts.

A target must be legal not only when a spell is cast, but also when it resolves:

> 608. Resolving Spells and Abilities
>
>      > 608.1. Each time all players pass in succession, the spell or ability on top of the stack resolves. (See rule 609, “Effects.”)
>      >
>      > > 608.2b If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal.